# How to redirect with envoy proxy

Tags: http-redirect, envoyproxy

We use envoy proxy as an ingress HTTP proxy. Now we would like to have a redirect from `https:/our_domain/` to `https:/our_domain/static/index.html`.
All our attempts failed so far, for example

```
          routes:
          - match:
              path: "/"
            redirect: { path_redirect: "/static/index.html" }
          - match:
              prefix: "/"
            route:
              prefix_rewrite: "/"
              cluster: our_cluster
```

How to configure routing for this use case? Please no Lua solution.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that the envoy proxy is behind a tls-terminating proxy. The redirect is therefore always with a http scheme, which is not served by the tls-terminating proxy.

The solution is

> https_redirect
> (bool) The scheme portion of the URL will be swapped with “https”.

The correct routing must thus be

```
      routes:
      - match:
          path: "/"
        redirect:
          https_redirect: true
          path_redirect: "/static/index.html"
      - match:
          prefix: "/"
        route:
          cluster: our_cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix “/“ matches any request so you just redirect endlessly. Set up a route that matches prefix “/static” *in front of* the catch all one and forward to it to an upstream cluster to provide a response. (For static files you could also serve them directly from Envoy.)

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: listener_http
    address:
      socket_address: 
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
  filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config: 
          codec_type : auto 
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                redirect:
                  path_redirect: "/"
                  https_redirect: true

          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
```

put this code before your listerner of https section to redirect all request

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you should add this code in listerner  part on fileenvoy.yaml

Comment: Are you sure that this could work? I think you will get the error about "redirect too many times".

Comment: Have you exemple of redirection for envoy apiv3 ? @Yves